# Unable to connect to redis sentinal in docker from my pc

Tags: java, docker, redis

i am running redis with sentinel in docker and I am not able to connect to my redis using the sentinel. This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
        - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
        - REDIS_PASSWORD=str0ng_passw0rd
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - '6379'
  redis-slave:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
        - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
        - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=redis
        - REDIS_MASTER_PASSWORD=str0ng_passw0rd
        - REDIS_PASSWORD=str0ng_passw0rd
    ports:
        - '6379'
    depends_on:
        - redis
    networks:
        - app-tier
  redis-sentinel:
    image: 'bitnami/redis-sentinel:latest'
    environment:
        - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=redis
        - REDIS_MASTER_PASSWORD=str0ng_passw0rd
    depends_on:
        - redis
        - redis-slave
    ports:
        - '26379:26379'
    networks:
        - app-tier
```

I can see that my sentinetl is up and running and have access to master and slave:

```
docker exec redis-image_redis-sentinel_1 redis-cli -p 26379 info sentinel
# Sentinel
sentinel_masters:1
sentinel_tilt:0
sentinel_running_scripts:0
sentinel_scripts_queue_length:0
sentinel_simulate_failure_flags:0
master0:name=mymaster,status=ok,address=172.23.0.2:6379,slaves=1,sentinels=1
```

But when I am accessing to redis from my local PC outside the docker network from java I am getting this output:

```
 redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
INFO: Trying to find master from available Sentinels...
 redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initSentinels
INFO: Redis master running at 172.23.0.2:6379, starting Sentinel listeners...
 redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool initPool
INFO: Created JedisPool to master at 172.23.0.2:6379
from master
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.getResource(JedisSentinelPool.java:209)
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:80)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1677)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
    ... 9 more
```

Looks like I am getting internal docker network IP (172.23.0.2:6379) and I am not able to connect to the instance.

I am not able to find solution how to connect to redis with sentinals outside docker.

Thanks

Comment: Found any solution for this? Having the same problem :S

Answer (score 1):

try to use this :

```
docker pull bitnami/redis
docker pull bitnami/redis-sentinel
docker network create redis-network --driver bridge
docker run --name redis-server -e ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -p 6379:6379 --network redis-network bitnami/redis
docker run --name redis-sentinel -it --rm -e REDIS_MASTER_HOST=127.0.0.1 -p 26379:26379 --network redis-network bitnami/redis-sentinel
```

you may connect to sentinel at 127.0.0.1:26379

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Both sentinel and redis are accessible via 127.0.0.1 that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still having this problem, but it looks like it is due to the port bindings on your "redis" and "redis-slave" containers.

If you use a single port number (e.g.  `- 6379`), Docker will bind that port on your container to a random port on your host. If you change it to something like  `- 6379:6379`, it will create the desired port bindings.

You can test this by running `docker container ls` and checking the values in the "ports" column.